# Angularfire2 - Assign a Observable to a FirebaseObjectObservable?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

how can I assign a Observable to a FirebaseObjectObservable?

At the moment I get the following error back

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<UserProfile[]>'.                                                                                                  
  Property '_ref' is missing in type '{}'.
```

**Method getUserProfile**

```
 getUserProfile() {
    const getUser = new Subject();
    this.getUser().subscribe(
        authResp => {
          console.log('response received from getUser():', authResp);
          const data = this.af.database.object(`users/${authResp}`);
          getUser.next(data);
          getUser.complete();
        },
        err => {
          getUser.error(err);
          getUser.complete();
        }
      )
     return getUser.asObservable();
   }
```

**Component**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;
  theUserProfile: FirebaseObjectObservable<UserProfile[]>;

  constructor(private authService:AuthService, private af: AngularFire, private auth: FirebaseAuth) {}

   ngOnInit() {
   this.sub = this.authService.getUserProfile().subscribe( data => {
      console.log('this is data:', data);
      this.theUserProfile = data;
   })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Question is: How can i assign the output of data to this.theUserProfile? The console.log('this is data:', data); gives back `this is data: FirebaseObjectObservable {_isScalar: false, _ref: U}`

Comment: Have you tried casting? Adding `<FirebaseObjectObservable<UserProfile[]>>` before calling your autService, something like this:  `this.sub = <FirebaseObjectObservable<UserProfile[]>> this.authService.getUserProfile().subscribe()`

Comment: Hi Fabio. Thanks for your answer. I have tried your example code without any luck. But you brought me in the right direction. I added the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fabio's suggestion I was able to answer my own question.

In needed to change the following in my component.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;
  theUserProfile;

  constructor(private authService:AuthService, private af: AngularFire, private auth: FirebaseAuth) {}

   ngOnInit() {
   this.sub = this.authService.getUserProfile().subscribe( data => {
      console.log('this is data:', data);
      this.theUserProfile = <FirebaseObjectObservable<UserProfile[]>>data;
   })
```